# jQuery validation plug-in warning-only custom rule

Tags: jquery-validate

In the jQuery validation plug-in from bassistance, is it possible to define a custom rule which displays an error message but does not block the user from submitting the form?

We have one particular field for which the software should give the user feedback on whether or not the provided value was found in an external system. But we leave it up to the user to decide on the validity of their input. In particular:

- `$(from).validate().element(field)` must return `true` even if the validator method returns false.
- But the same call must cause a validation message to appear.
- And all other validation rules still must be treated as usual. They block the submission if any value is invalid.

Comment: Did you discover whether warnings are possible?

Comment: @Dave: Haven't investigated on that anymore... I'm afraid it's not (yet) part of the plug-in.